# Scikit learn - fit_transform on the test set

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, random-forest, text-classification

I am struggling to use Random Forest in Python with Scikit learn. My problem is that I use it for text classification (in 3 classes - positive/negative/neutral) and the features that I extract are mainly words/unigrams, so I need to convert these to numerical features. I found a way to do it with `DictVectorizer`'s `fit_transform`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

vec = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 100)
trainFeatures1 = vec.fit_transform(trainFeatures)

# Fit the training data to the training output and create the decision trees
rf = rf.fit(trainFeatures1.toarray(), LabelEncoder().fit_transform(trainLabels))

testFeatures1 = vec.fit_transform(testFeatures)
# Take the same decision trees and run on the test data
Output = rf.score(testFeatures1.toarray(), LabelEncoder().fit_transform(testLabels))

print "accuracy: " + str(Output)
```

My problem is that the `fit_transform` method is working on the train dataset, which contains around 8000 instances, but when I try to convert my test set to numerical features too, which is around 80000 instances, I get a memory error saying that:

```
testFeatures1 = vec.fit_transform(testFeatures)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\dict_vectorizer.py", line 143, in fit_transform
return self.transform(X)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\dict_vectorizer.py", line 251, in transform
Xa = np.zeros((len(X), len(vocab)), dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

What could possibly cause this and is there any workaround? Many thanks!

Comment: Can you try using sparse features?  I don't think the toarray() calls should be needed.

Comment: scikit-learn's RandomForestClassifier doesn't take sparse matrices as an input. One solution is to split your test set into batches of a certain size, then run predict on each of the smaller batches.

Comment: @rrenaud I also tried this by creating the vec object as vec = DicVectorizer(). It still didn't help..

Comment: @Matt Indeed, that's why I used sparse=False.

Comment: Another solution is to use `TfIdfVectorizer` followed by a `TruncatedSVD` to reduce the dimensionality of the feature space.

Comment: You don't need the `LabelEncoder`. The `y` may contain strings.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are not supposed to do `fit_transform` on your test data, but only `transform`. Otherwise, you will get different vectorization than the one used during training.

For the memory issue, I recommend `TfIdfVectorizer`, which has numerous options of reducing the dimensionality (by removing rare unigrams etc.).

**UPDATE**

If the only problem is fitting **test** data, simply split it to small chunks. Instead of something like

```
x=vect.transform(test)
eval(x)
```

you can do

```
K=10
for i in range(K):
    size=len(test)/K
    x=vect.transform(test[ i*size : (i+1)*size ])
    eval(x)
```

and record results/stats and analyze them afterwards.

in particular

```
predictions = []

K=10
for i in range(K):
    size=len(test)/K
    x=vect.transform(test[ i*size : (i+1)*size ])
    predictions += rf.predict(x) # assuming it retuns a list of labels, otherwise - convert it to list

print accuracy_score( predictions, true_labels )
```