# memory error when using sklearn feature extraction

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, nltk

I've been using a python script to tokenize and calculate the TFIDF for a lot of `.txt` files, my script is as follow :

```
import nltk
import string
import os

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
import string
from collections import Counter
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import re
import scipy.io
import glob

path = 'R'
token_dict = {}
stemmer = PorterStemmer()

def stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer):
    stemmed = []
    for item in tokens:
        stemmed.append(stemmer.stem(item))
    return stemmed

def tokenize(text):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    stems = stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer)
    return stems

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
 for file in files:
    #if re.match("text\d+.txt",file):
      #with open(os.path.join(path,file),'r') as f:
       #for shakes in f:

        remove_spl_char_regex = re.compile('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation)) # regex to remove special characters
        remove_num = re.compile('[\d]+')
        file_path = subdir + os.path.sep + file
        shakes = open(file_path, encoding="utf8")

        text = shakes.read()
        lowers = text.lower()
        a1 = lowers.translate(string.punctuation)
        a2 = remove_spl_char_regex.sub(" ",a1)  # Remove special characters
        a3 = remove_num.sub("", a2)  #Remove numbers
        token_dict[file] = a3

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenize, stop_words='english')
tfs = tfidf.fit_transform(token_dict.values())
scipy.io.savemat('arrdata4.mat', mdict={'arr': tfs})
```

Depending on the size of the file I encounter a MemoryError after 30 minutes.
Anyone can explain to me how can I increase the memory that python has access to or any other way that I can solve this problem with? .

Comment: Where are you getting MemoryError? While generating `tfidf` or while `fit_transform`?

Comment: I am getting the error while it generating the fit-transform

Comment: It seems like the issue reported in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22006707/522719. Did you try splitting the data while fitting?

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't have a memory limit beyond what the OS imposes.

- Make sure you're not limiting the process's memory usage with `ulimit` or equivalent.
- Run `top` and see if the process uses all available memory.
- Then you'll either have to decrease then memory your program needs, or increase the RAM/Swap it gets access to.