Ordinal encoding keeps showing the same value no matter the input value, thus making the prediction results the same
I am building a model that can predict that a patient is diagnose with chronic kidney disease
Below are the steps I used;

import the neccessary libraries for the training model and the dataset
impute the numerical columns with a random value and the categorical columns with the mode
perform oridinal encoding for the categorical columns
split the dataset into train and test values
there was a bias values in the dataset so I use SMOTE library to generate some dummy records to make the data balanced
I use decision tree classifier for the model

Here is my code;
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import math
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore')


df = pd.read_csv('kidney_disease.csv')
cat_cols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype == 'object']
num_cols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype != 'object']

from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
enc = OrdinalEncoder()

df_copied = df.copy()
X_enc = enc.fit_transform(df_copied[cat_cols])
df_copied[cat_cols] = pd.DataFrame(X_enc, columns=cat_cols)

x = df_copied.drop(['classification'], axis=1)
y = df_copied['classification']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 42)

from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

smote = SMOTE(random_state=42)
X_resampled, y_resampled = smote.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)

dtc = grid_search_dtc.best_estimator_

# accuracy score, confusion matrix and classification report of decision tree

dtc_acc = accuracy_score(y_test, dtc.predict(X_test))

dtcClassifier = 'dtc_model.pkl'
with open(dtcClassifier, 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(dtc, file)


I use streamlit library to implement my model
with open('dtc_model.pkl', 'rb') as file:  
    model = pickle.load(file)

# Define the column names
cols = ["age", "bp", "sg", "al", "su", "rbc", "pc", "pcc", "ba", "bgr", "bu", "sc", "sod", "pot", "hemo", "pcv", "wc", "rc", "htn", "dm", "cad", "appet", "pe", "ane"]

def main():
    st.title("Kidney Disease Prediction Using Hybrid Model")
  
   
        
    html_temp = """
    <div style="background:#025246 ;padding:10px">
    <h2 style="color:white;text-align:center;">KD Prediction App </h2>
    </div>
    """
    st.markdown(html_temp, unsafe_allow_html = True)
    
    # Define input fields
    age = st.text_input("Age", 0)
    bp = st.text_input("Blood Pressure", 0)
    sg = st.selectbox("Specific Gravity", [0, 1.005, 1.010, 1.015, 1.020, 1.025])
    al = st.selectbox("Albumin", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    su = st.selectbox("Sugar", [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    rbc = st.selectbox("Red Blood Cells", ["", "normal", "abnormal"])
    pc = st.selectbox("Pus Cell", ["", "normal", "abnormal"])
    pcc = st.selectbox("Pus Cell clumps", ["", "present", "notpresent"])
    ba = st.selectbox("Bacteria", ["", "present", "notpresent"])
    bgr = st.text_input("Blood Glucose Random", 0)
    bu = st.text_input("Blood Urea", 0)
    sc = st.text_input("Serum Creatinine", 0)
    sod = st.text_input("Sodium", 0)
    pot = st.text_input("Potassium", 0)
    hemo = st.text_input("Hemoglobin", 0)
    pcv = st.text_input("Packed Cell Volume", 0)
    wc = st.text_input("White Blood Cell Count", 0)
    rc = st.text_input("Red Blood Cell Count", 0)
    htn = st.selectbox("Hypertension", ["", "yes", "no"])
    dm = st.selectbox("Diabetes Mellitus", ["", "yes", "no"])
    cad = st.selectbox("Coronary Artery Disease", ["", "yes", "no"])
    appet = st.selectbox("Appetite", ["", "good", "poor"])
    pe = st.selectbox("Pedal Edema", ["", "yes", "no"])
    ane = st.selectbox("Anemia", ["", "yes", "no"])
    
   
    
    if st.button("Predict"):
        
        # Convert data to DataFrame
        data = {
                'age': int(age), 
                'bp': float(bp), 
                'sg': sg, 
                'al': al, 
                'su': su, 
                'rbc': rbc, 
                'pc': pc,
                'pcc': pcc,
                'ba': ba, 
                'bgr': float(bgr), 
                'bu': float(bu), 
                'sc': float(sc), 
                'sod': float(sod), 
                'pot': float(pot), 
                'hemo': float(hemo), 
                'pcv': float(pcv), 
                'wc': float(wc), 
                'rc': float(rc), 
                'htn': htn, 
                'dm': dm, 
                'cad': cad, 
                'appet': appet, 
                'pe': pe, 
                'ane': ane
        }
        
        df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns=cols)
        # Check if all input fields are filled
        # Convert data to DataFrame
       
        
        
        cat_cols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].dtype == 'object']
        enc = OrdinalEncoder()

        df_copied = df.copy()
        df_copied[cat_cols] = enc.fit_transform(df_copied[cat_cols])
        
        print(pd.DataFrame(df_copied))
        
        prediction = model.predict(df_copied)
        print(prediction[0])
        
        # Display prediction result
        if prediction[0] == 1:
                st.write("Positive")
        else:
                st.write("Negative")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

When I print the df_copied in Dataframe format, I notice that the cat_cols is always 0
I tried LabelEncoder() but is the same

Maybe first use print() (and print(type(...)), print(len(...)), etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called "print debuging" and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Hi, thanks for the reply. I have store the categorical values explicitly and perform fit_transform func on the encoder so now it changes due to the change in input fields. And I have print the all the data values to the console to see the values yet my model stills give me the same answer irrespective of the input feeds.

You need to store the ordinal encoder from training and use it to transform the incoming data from streamlit, rather than creating a new encoder (which only ever sees one value, and so only ever assigns it value 0, regardless of what that value was).

This has to be a duplicate, but all the ones I can find have a slightly different flavor. // https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/54052/55122 // https://stackoverflow.com/q/21998008/10495893 // https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/595553/232706
